# Is there a way to have Files file manager in 18.04 search inside scripts?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

This is for 18.04. Is there a way to have Files look inside R scripts? I already have 'Full Text Search' in preferences set, but evidently it doesn't include .R endings.

I tried SearchMonkey - it does the job but it is very slow (couldn't find a setting to index files/contents), and crashes often.

Comment: FWIW, you could do this from the command line: Enable globstar if it's not already on: `shopt -s globstar`; search: `grep "something" **.R **.r`